# Can't access remote PostreSQL

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I just moved my office and now I can't get to PostgreSQL on my Windows web server.

I changed the pg_hba.conf file to the new IP address. I made no other changes to the server or my computer.

One known difference is that I am temporarily using a public xfinitywifi hotspot until my new cable internet is set up, which may be a few more days. And yes, I know this hotspot uses a dynamic IP, I am using WhatIsMyIP to get the IP to use in the pg_hba.conf.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? If WhatIsMyIP giving me the correct IP address to use in this context?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: Chances are, Comcast is blocking the access.

Comment: @Hyppy, why would it do that and how? Is is blocking the port?

Comment: It's a consumer-level hotspot. They block all sorts of stuff.

Comment: I got my real internet connection and it still is not working. I emailed my ISP and they say the port is being filtered. My server firewall rule still looks good, so any ideas how it is getting filtered?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had locked down which external IP address I could use within the firewall rule. So port 5432 was being seen as filtered from any other IP address.

Maybe that is overkill, using both the firewall and pg_hba.conf to limit access to a specific external IP address?

- Brad